# Vlookup search column

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm attempting to write a Vlookup command in Excel and I'm getting incorrect results

My data is set up in a table called "Ranking" and  I've sorted the data in descending order according to the Time Column, What I have looks something like this:

```
   Rank   Name   Data1  Data2  Data3  Data4  Time
   1      Frank   XX     xx     xx     xx    163.2
   2      Jim     XX     xx     xx     xx    150.0
   3      Jane    XX     xx     xx     xx    113.9
 ...
8022      Paco    XX     xx     xx     xx     10.2
8023      Tim     XX     xx     xx     xx     10.0
8023      Lana    XX     xx     xx     xx     10.0
8024      Sara    XX     xx     xx     xx     9.99
...
```

With several thousand rows of data. Occasionally two rows will have the same rank meaning that I can't just use the row number to determine the rank.

What I'm trying to do is given a search value, find the closest Rank number. So if I were to search for 149, I would get 3, if I were to search for 10.1 I would get 8023.

Using Cell K9 as my search entry value, what I'm trying to use is:

```
=VLOOKUP(K9,Rankings,7,True)
```

My understanding from the documentation this says, "find the value specified in Cell K9, from table "Rankings" in the seventh column of the table. And if the value doesn't exist, take the next row down".

I'm pretty sure that my understanding of how VLOOKUP works is incorrect here?? Am I at least close to doing what I'm trying to do?

I'm running 2010 Excel, I know there are a few new tools, that I don't have access to. Many thanks!

Comment: For VLOOKUP, the lookup value has to be in the leftmost column. INDEX/MATCH.

Comment: That's good to know!!! I've moved my Time column to the left of Rank column, and changed the 7 to 2. This seems to need to be in ascending order to work though, is it possible to have it work  in descending order

Comment: Use INDEX/MATCH still - MATCH can work with either ascending or descending order (and you're going to have a follow up question, but I'll let you take a stab at it).

Comment: =INDEX(Rankings[Rank],MATCH(K9,Rankings[Time],-1)) Seems to work great?? I'm guessing the follow up you were expecting was how to deal with switching between ascending and descending order? My approach would be to wrap the INDEX/MATCH in an if statement to check for the ordering and change the -1 to +1 depending on the order?

Comment: I assumed you'd have a follow-up question on `-1`... you'd have to handle the case where there is an *exact* match, otherwise you'd be off by 1 row.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for the advice and suggestion, I much prefer the INDEX/MATCH approach to VLOOKUP, you end up having a little more control over what's going on. If you were to put that up as an answer I'll give you the points for it. It was your solution, after all.